# How can I convert an empty pandas dataframe to Pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'd like a safe way to convert a pandas dataframe to a pyspark dataframe which can handle cases where the pandas dataframe is empty (lets say after some filter has been applied). For example the following will fail:

**Assumes you have a spark session**

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = []
cols = ['col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3']
types_dict = {
    'col_1': str,
    'col_2': float,
    'col_3': bool
}
pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=cols).astype(types_dict)
spark_df = spark.createDataframe(pandas_df)
```

Resulting error:
`ValueError: can not infer schema from empty dataset`

One option is to build a function which could iterate through the pandas dtypes and construct a Pyspark dataframe schema, but that could get a little complicated with structs and whatnot. Is there a simpler solution?

How can I convert an empty pandas dataframe to a Pyspark dataframe and maintain the column datatypes?

Comment: Using pyspark is not as straightforward as ti seems. In my case I had to build a container in docker in order to be able to use spark. Another option is to have Linux as OS.

Comment: Use try, except block. If it is empty data frame put just schema in except block.

Comment: yes, the safest way is to create a schema that can be passed to the `createDataFrame()`

Comment: Maybe you can find my answer from another thread helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76637811/3081328

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your problem try something with try-except block.

```
def test(df):
       try:
          """
          What ever the operations you want on your df.
          """
       except:
          df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': pd.Series(dtype='str'),
               'col_2': pd.Series(dtype='float'),
               'col_3': pd.Series(dtype='bool'),
               })
return df
```

Comment: Thanks! Only issue with this is I'd lose the datatype info from the empty pandas df, which ideally I'd like to keep and create a matching empty pyspark df

Comment: Check the updated answer. I believe you will get desired datatypes as well. If yes accept it and close it.