# can not infer schema from empty dataset

Tags: azure-databricks

I have written a below query :

- Convert spark dataframes from bronze to pandas dataframes to transform data and merge different source objects into one business entity

```py
salesforce_pd_df = delta_df.toPandas()
```

- Rename columns using business names of data object like in CDM - Common Data Model

```py
salesforce_pd_df = salesforce_pd_df.rename (
    {
        '_change_type':'Change_Type',
        '_commit_version':'Commit_Version',
        '_commit_timestamp':'Commit_Timestamp'
        }, axis='columns' )

print("after renaming columns: \n")
display(salesforce_pd_df)
```

- create spark dataframe from converted pandas dataframe in order to write to Dedicated sql pool

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(salesforce_pd_df)
```

But i am getting error : `can not infer schema from empty dataset`
Please advise

Comment: Try getting a record count.  It is stating that the dataset is empty.  An empty RDD has no schema definition.

Comment: Why are you going to pandas in the first place.  This will take processing time.  If the data is in spark, use the following methods to rename and/or create a new column:  withColumnRenamed() vs withColumn()

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty easy way to handle empty df:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType

if df.empty:
    sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df, schema=StructType())
else:
    sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

if the schema itself is still relevant for empty df and you want to keep that, you can do it with a method similar to below:

```
def build_schema(df) -> StructType:
    fields = []
    for field_name, field_type in dict(df.dtypes).items():
        if field_type == dtype("O"):
            type_ = StringType()
        elif field_type == dtype("int32"):
            type_ = IntegerType()
        elif field_type == dtype("int64"):
            type_ = LongType()
        elif field_type == dtype("float32"):
            type_ = FloatType()
        elif field_type == dtype("float64"):
            type_ = DoubleType()
        elif field_type == dtype("bool"):
            type_ = BooleanType()
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"Type: {field_type} is not handled!")

        fields.append(StructField(field_name, type_, True))

    schema = StructType(fields)
    return schema
```

and then use this function to convert with empty df schema:

```
sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df, schema=build_schema(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Can not infer schema from empty dataset.**

The above error mainly happen because of `delta_df` Data frame is empty.

> **Note:** when you convert pandas dataframe using `delta_df.toPandas()`, the resulting dataframe is also empty. As a result, when you try to create a spark dataframe from the pandas the  dataframe , the method is unable to **infer the schema** because there are no rows in the dataframe.

To resolve the issue  ,Either check if `delta_df` is not empty before converting it to a pandas dataframe or add sample data to `delta_df` so that there are rows in the dataframe.

I reproduce same thing in my environment. I got this output with sample data.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType

schema1 = StructType([
    StructField("_change_type", StringType(), True),
    StructField("_commit_version", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("_commit_timestamp", StringType(), True)
])

d1 = [("insert1", 1, "2023-03-13 00:00:00"),
        ("update1", 2, "2023-03-13 01:00:00"),
        ("delete1", 3, "2023-03-13 02:00:00")]


df1 = spark.createDataFrame(d1, schema1)

pd_df = df1.toPandas()

pd_df1 = pd_df.rename(
    {"_change_type": "Change_Type", "_commit_version": "Commit_Version", "_commit_timestamp": "Commit_Timestamp"},
    axis="columns"
)
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd_df1)
display(df)
```

[image]

[image]